# Continuity of $\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have to prove that 
$\root{3}\of{x}$ is continuous everywhere. For this take a point $a\in\mathbb{R}$. For this to be continuous we need to find a $\delta$ for each $\epsilon$. 
$$|\root{3}\of x-\root 3\of a|<\epsilon$$
Find a $\delta$ for when the above holds such that $|x-a| <\delta$. 
$$|\root 3\of x - \root 3 \of a|\cdot|\root 3\of {x^2} + \root 3 \of{xa}+ \root 3 \of {a^2}|<\delta$$
Can't think how to proceed to get $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I do not think you have to try it that way. Take $\sqrt x$; as you know it is continuous because in its natural domain there are no "jumps" or discontinuities (except perhaps in $0$, but the image at that point and the limit exist, and are the same). Therefore, by property, $\sqrt x\cdot\sqrt x\cdot\sqrt x$ is continuous (product of continuous is continuous).

Comment: But then you assume that all this is true for $\sqrt{x}$. Here I only want to use the definition of continuity to prove this.

Comment: The continuity of a function at any point is such if and only if the graph can be traced draw in a single stroke, without jumps.

Comment: Yes that is true however that isn't the rigorous definition. The rigorous definition is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition. In  this see Weierstrass and Jordan definitions (epsilon–delta) of continuous functions

Comment: @manooooh First, the cube root of $x$ is not the cube of the square root of $x$. Second, one has to prove that the product of continuous functions is continuous using $\epsilon$-$\delta$, which is less straightforward than to continue with what the OP has done.

Comment: It would be easier if you write $x=ca$ where $c$ is close to $1$.  Then you can factor out $\sqrt[3]{a}$ so you just need that $|\sqrt[3]{c}-1|$ is small.  Essentially you reduce the problem to continuity at $1.$

Comment: Oh, I forgot that @hellotinfish... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$|x-y| \le 1$
and
$0 <a <x, y < b$,
then,
since
$u^n-v^n
=(u-v)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} u^kv^{n-1-k}
$,
$x-y
=(x^{1/n}-y^{1/n})\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k/n}y^{(n-1-k)/n}
$
so
$|x-y|
\gt|x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}||\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k/n}a^{(n-1-k)/n}|
=|x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}|a^{(n-1)/n}
$,
so that
$|x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}|
\lt \dfrac{|x-y|}{a^{(n-1)/n}}
$.

This should be enough
to get a $\delta-\epsilon$
proof.

Comment: What is the use of $y<b$?

Comment: It is not needed. I was working this out as I went along, so I initially put that in there. If I wanted to clean it up, I would remove that.

Answer (score 0):

simply note that $\sqrt[n]{a-b} \geq \sqrt[n]a - \sqrt[n]b$ for all $a \geq b \geq 0$ .This can be proved by considering $t = \frac{a}{b} \in (0,1]$ and $t^{1/n} \geq t$ or some other tricks.